# Delphi String unreliable

Tags: string, delphi, pascal

Hello im currently creating a pretty heavy application which relay on another applications threads and also grabs the handle. therefore if that application would freeze so does mine and it does lag a bit form time to time while the target software does heavy loading)

The issue is that if somehow the more heavy application "Lag" i get unexpected issues with strings and they give me unreliable outputs.

Anyone have any idea why this is happening and how i can solve this or work around this?

My currently solution i have been using is belove, however thats not really what i want to do since it does make the runtime very unreliable due to the fact i cant be sure about the outcome.

```
function GetInt(MyNum:string):integer;
begin
  try
    result := strtoint(MyNum);
  except
    result := 0;
  end;
end;
```

---

As an example i made this script and suddenly i got the $ReBEFF is not a valid integer. (all of the sudden it have been running fine for hours)

oldB is a Byte which is handles as a number converted to hexadecimal. oldB is set to always 0 it should never change especially not to Re which is not even within the hexadecimal number system

```
xx0000 = B
00xx00 = G
0000xx = R
```

example script (this is not the only codepart which have had issues with strings, it appers randomly for no reason all over the application)

```
var
  oldR:byte = 0;
  oldG:byte = 30;
  oldB:byte = 0;
  _Down:bool = false;

function GetColor(R, G, B:byte):integer;
var
  MyColor:string;
begin
  MyColor := '';
  MyColor := MyColor + inttohex(B, 2);
  MyColor := MyColor + inttohex(G, 2);
  MyColor := MyColor + inttohex(R, 2);
  result := strtoint('$' + MyColor);
end;

procedure TMainF.DonateColorTimer(Sender: TObject);
var
  MyColor:integer;
begin

  oldR := 255;

  if _Down then begin
    dec(oldG, 10);
    if oldG <= 0+30 then
      _Down := false;
  end else begin
    inc(oldG, 10);
    if oldG >= 255-30 then
      _down := true;
  end;

  oldB := 0;

  MyColor := GetColor(oldR, oldG, oldB);

  if MyColor = 0 then
    exit;

  Label32.Font.Color := MyColor;
  Label33.Font.Color := MyColor;
end;
```

---

When i did stress my application i did manage to get access error FFFFFFFC (-1 in an array?) in a codepart of the application which is in the structure itself not in my codeparts (the codepart was running even before my GUI is created when i rerun the application and tested with a debugger) sadly i cant manage to to repeat to locate it.

however it feels that somehow some function from the "library in delphi" cant handle the "lag" and it overlap itself and messup the string.

Im using RAD Studio XE 8

Another Example that got messedup all of the sudden

```
function GetAppPath:string;
var
  Buffer: Array[0..260] of Char;
  Path:string;
begin
  try
    GetModuleFileName(hInstance, Buffer, Length(Buffer));
    Path := ExtractFilePath(Buffer);
    result := Path;
  except
  end;
end;

Should have returned D:\Download\Finished\Apps\
returned D:\Download\Finished\A#ps\
```

Comment: Delphi apps are not inherently unreliable, neither are their string operations.  These symptoms sound like a classic case of self-inflicted memory corruption/overwrites.  Two qs:  Does your app do all its work in the VCL thread?  Have you tried turning on "full debug mode" in the RTL memory manager?

Comment: The code snippets by themself can not produce the problems you are describing. I would focus on what you said in the first paragraph and make sure the interaction between the two applications is robust. Btw, your conversion of `R`, `G` and `B` to an integer via a hex string is really inefficient. Replace with the one-liner: `result := B shl 16 or G shl 8 or R;`.

Answer (score 14):

The symptoms that you describe are those of memory corruption because of a defect in your code. The library functions that you are calling have no known defects that could produce these symptoms. With probability close to 1 the defect is in your code.

A common defect that would have these symptoms is writing to memory after it has been freed. You'd observe such symptoms if the memory manager re-used the freed memory for a new allocation.

You will need to do some more fact finding debugging to identify the source of the defects. FastMM in full debug mode would be a good tool to start investigating. But you may need more than just tools.

Let me make this clear in case you've missed my point. All the evidence points to the defect being in your code.

Now, some specific comments on the code that we can see:

It concerns me that you appear to have placed swallow all exception handling in multiple places in your code. As a general rule you should not handle exceptions. You should let exceptions propagate up the call stack. Start by removing all these swallow all exception handlers.

Your call to the Windows API `GetModuleFileName` ignores the return value. Windows API functions don't raise exceptions and instead, typically, indicate success or failure through the return value. Please consult the documentation of all Windows API functions that you call.

Your use of global variables is rather concerning. Those globals that we can see should be fields of `TMainF`. Perhaps you have other globals that are causing problems.

You should give your controls meaningful names. `Label32` conveys no meaning to the reader of the code, normally you. Don't let the IDE write your code.

Converting from color channel values to an RGB value should be done with bitwise operations. There's no place at all for text conversions.

```
Color := B shl 16 or G shl 8 or R;
```

Comment: I guess this hexadecimal / string trick comes from a JavaScript or php background...

Comment: I do agree that there are better ways of doing it always going to be, however that doesnt change the fact that that just that code outputs something that it shouldnt be able too

oldB:byte := 0;  1byte = 255 = 0xFF inttohex(oldB) never "Re"
The issue accure when the target application "freeze" for a moment before that everything runs fine for hours. as you mention it "writing to memory after it has been freed" sounds very reasonable
On that note its a local variable that returns the wrong value, doesnt matter what value oldB would have it would always return a hexadecimal value with most 255

Comment: It sounds like you don't want to admit that there could be a defect in your program. Local or global? They can both be corrupted. A string is stored on the heap so whether or not the variable that points to it is local, heap corruption is still possible. I'm not at all trying to suggest that your RGB conversion implementation is at fault. I'm just pointing out that it is sub-optimal. Your defect lies elsewhere.

Comment: I dont denie that there could be ofcourse not. people always fix issues with their applications when a bug error accure and its always nice to learn something new ;)

however the way the error presents it feels that some function overlap itself when the target software freeze and that way the strings turn bad. 


since local variables are located in the stack (i think?) could it be that when the thread freeze another thread push another value to the stack and therefore returns the wrong value?

im not really sure if thats possible. if you have any other suggestions im happy to hear.

Comment: I'm not going to argue with you. If you don't want to hear what I have to say, feel free to ignore me.

Comment: Anyway found the issue and it was infact a memoryleak however not due to my code but due to the lag as i expected.

When using a local TStringList and the App freeze somehow things got messedup with the allocation. replacing it with a fixed size of array of strings solved the issue.

Comment: That's nonsense. You are making this up. Lag?!! You don't understand any of this. And you won't listen to those that do. Good luck!